# Multiple keyword select from a string of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a post having tags in between. So I'm trying to retrieve all the keyword which are followed by # using simple regex expression.

```
var hashtag = $('p').text().match(/#\w+\s/);
console.log(hashtag);
```

I'm using the `.match()` function to find the match of the defined regex expression, but it is only displaying one keyword, whereas I have two.

Is there any way to retrieve multiple keywords?

Comment: `match` isn't a "jQuery function." It's a JavaScript standard library function. jQuery is just a DOM manipulation library (plus some utilities).

Comment: `.match(/#\w+\s?/g)` maybe? Should be global and and the space on the end is optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var hashtag = $('p').text().match(/#\w*\s*/gi);
console.log(hashtag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>#this is #the#text with#regular#expression hash #tags</p>
```

Comment: this will work for all possible combination of inputes

Comment: this one is much better approach. Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the `g` flag to your regex (`/#\w+\s/g`):

```js
var hashtag = $('p').text().match(/#\w+\s/g);
console.log(hashtag);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
This is some text that #has #hash #tags
</p>
```

Comment: I've tried that already. That does not help. I think the .match() function returns only single value.

Comment: @ujjwalverma That's not true. You can run the code snippet and see it working fine using `match()`...

Comment: this will not work as intended if I give this input :   <p>#dinesh dfgdfg #ravi#xyz dfgdfg#EEE#rty gbghgf #SOLUTION</p>

Comment: I was doing something wrong at my end. Got stuck in loops. It worked though. Thanks.